# jQuery eq() caused infinite iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, iteration

When I try to sum things up in my code, I figured out when I write something like this:

```
var $elements = $('div');
for ( var i = 0, $element; $element = $elements.eq(i); i++ ) {
    $element.text( 'Hello' );
}
```

the loop will never end. I would like to know, why that is happening. Caused it an error if I call functions inside condition or does jQuery just not return accurate data so therefore the loop-condition can't recognize the current index?

Comment: In the `i` declaration you also reassign $element to i

Comment: what do you mean with $elements.eq(i) ?? what its output should be?

Comment: `$element = $elements.eq(i)` is supposed to return the `i`th element in the collection wrapped in a jQuery object. I'm pretty sure OP was hoping it would fail after there wasn't an `i`th element.

Comment: My output should be the jQuery object for each div element. I tried to avoid to assign the variable inside the loop, rather in the condition. Of course I can just iterate trough the array of elements, but then I must still create a jQuery object to access jQuery methods.

Comment: Why are you reinventing jQuery's each?

Comment: Because jQuery's `.each()` callback parameters are DOM objects and no jQuery objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.eq()` method always returns a jQuery object. If you specify an index that doesn't exist you get an empty jQuery object. But any object is truthy, so your loop condition is always truthy even after `i` goes past the last element. So, infinite loop.

You need to test the length:

```
for ( var i = 0, $element; i < $elements.length && ($element = $elements.eq(i)) ; i++ )
```

But why not just use the `.each()` method to loop?

The pattern of assigning the current element as the loop condition does work with an array:

```
for ( var i = 0, element; element = anArray[i]; i++ )
```

assuming none of the elements have a falsey value, because when `i` reaches `an array.length` then `anArray[i]` will be `undefined` which is falsey.

Comment: **Invalid left-hand side in assignment** `i < $elements.length && $element = $elements.eq(i)` looks invalid.

Comment: @kindisch - Oops. I've added parentheses. And a recommendation to use `.each()`  instead.

Comment: I like to work with jQuery less as possible because it slows things down. Would you say, that `.each()` will be faster in this case? With `.each()` I must still assign the jQuery Object.

Comment: Thank you both of you. _nnnnnn_ and _Mike C._ I little bit struggeled who should be rewarded, but I end up at _nnnnnn_ because he puts the cherry on the cake for his example how to use jQuery `.eq()` inside the condition correctly.

Comment: .each() is slower than a plain for loop, but how much slower depends on what you're doing in the loop. In most "normal" cases the user won't notice the difference. I assume your real code does something more than just assign the same text to every element (because if that's all you want to do you can do it in one line with `$elements.text("hello")`), but sometimes in an .each() loop you don't need the individual elements as jQuery objects, you can just access `this.value` or some other property directly.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$` and, in turn, `$elements.eq` will always return an object, even if nothing matches the query. That object will have a length of 0 but it will still be an object. Objects are truthy values.

```js
function log(msg) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText += msg + '\n';
}

log($('p').eq(0)); // First p element
log($('p').eq(1)); // Second p element
log($('p').eq(2)); // Third p element
log($('p').eq(3)); // No matching p element but look at what we get

if ($('p').eq(9001)) {
  log('Yup, still a truthy value');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>

<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you both of you. _nnnnnn_ and _Mike C._ I little bit struggeled who should be rewarded, but I end up at _nnnnnn_ because he puts the cherry on the cake for his example how to use jQuery `.eq()` inside the condition correctly.